# Problem with network interface

Tags: networking

I had a problem with eth0 interface.
I installed linux distribution version 11.10 and I want to set static IP address to my linux computer. When I run `ifconfig`, it didn't print the eth0 interface. It seems it isn't detected by the system, even if I edit the file `/etc/network/interfaces` this way :

```
auto eth0 
iface eth0 inet static
address = x.x.x.x
netmask = x.x.x.x
getway = x.x.x.x
```

Is there any solution to set static ip address to my computer or any solution to enable eth0 interface when I run ifconfig command in terminal ?

Comment: "Linux  distribution" isn't a real thing. Something can be _a_ Linux distribution - which one did you install?

Comment: Try inserting the line `auto eth0` above the text you've put in the `interfaces` file.

Comment: Dear Flup i added auto eth0 before if you read my question properly and one thing more i want to say when we run ifconfig command there should be lo interface and eth0 interface with all the specification so i didn't have eth0 so please help me in this problem if possible

Comment: Which Linux distribution? What does `ifconfig -a` report? What network adapter do you have (if you don't know, copy-paste the output of `lspci`)?

Comment: Dear linux Expert Gilles :   i Used Ubuntu 11.10 please Add me in you Skype ID : Farhad.paywast

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a `ifup eth0` will help you ? and something like `service networking stop/start` or `/etc/init.d/networking stop/start`

Comment: i did the following things that you mention so please help me if you had any good idea or solution that is to be useful for what i want

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer: Assuming you installed Ubuntu 11.10, it sounds like the kernel included is too old to recognize your ethernet controller--it dates from 2011, after all! Try installing a [newer version](http://www.ubuntu.com/download).

Further diagnosis: Run `lspci -k` to see if any Ethernet interfaces are present on your system. On my system, for instance, I see:

```
00:03.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation PRO/1000 MT Desktop Adapter
    Kernel driver in use: e1000
```

If you see something like that, but *without* the `Kernel driver in use` bit, then install the newer version of Ubuntu. If you do see `Kernel driver in use`, then run `ip link` to see the names of all the network interfaces on your system. On mine, I can see other other interface, besides `lo`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:57:10:b2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: I installed the newer version as well like 12.04 but again i have the same problem so i think it is disable or  my network interface card fault